# Xml to Json conversion ignores deepest level attributes

Tags: php, xml, json, parent-child, cdata

I've made a simple PHP script that converts an `XML` file to a `JSON` file.
Here is a code snippet:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
$json = json_encode(new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOCDATA));
```

My `XML` is nicely being converted to `JSON`. Except for one thing:
the attributes of the deepest child-tags (in XML) are not added to the `JSON`.
(these deepest child tags have no child tags of their own, they just have an attribute and contain some `CDATA` text.)

It's weird because attributes of tags which have child-tags are being added.

I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report about xml to json conversion in php: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54632

Check and see where you lose the data with var_dumps.

Comment: I've done that, I lose the data here: new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML()

Comment: Class SimpleXMLElement { final public __construct ( string $data [, int $options = 0 [, bool $data_is_url = false [, string $ns = "" [, bool $is_prefix = false ]]]] ) ... }    The constructor of the SimpleXMLElement takes argument as string and your $xml variable is allready formated as xml. could be a problem